# Mat cells set to NULL in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, null, mat

Quick summary:

I create a cv::Mat by

```
cv::Mat m = cv::Mat::zeros(MAP_HEIGHT, MAP_WIDTH, CV_8UC1)
```

My approach after this is to see if i have any polygons in a list of polygons, and if i do, fill them in, and lastly i assign m to my public cv::Mat map (defined in the header-file).
What happens is basically:

```
cv::Mat m = cv::Mat::zeros(MAP_HEIGHT, MAP_WIDTH, CV_8UC1);
// possibly fill polygons with 1's. Nothing happens if there are no polygons
map = m;
```

The logic of my program is that position x,y is allowed if a 0 is occupying the cell. So no polygons => all map should be 'legit'.

I have defined this method to check whether a given x-y coordinate is allowed.

```
bool Map::isAllowed(bool res, int x, int y) {
    unsigned char allowed = 0;
    res = (map.ptr<unsigned char>(y)[x] == allowed);
}
```

Now the mystery begins.

```
cout << cv::countNonZero(map) << endl; // prints 0, meaning all cells are 0
for(int i = 0; i < MAP_HEIGHT; i++) {
    unsigned char* c = map.ptr<unsigned char>(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < MAP_WIDTH; j++) {
        cout << c[j] << endl;
    }
} // will print nothing, only outputs empty lines, followed by a newline.
```

If i print (c[j] == NULL) it prints 1.
If i print the entire Mat i see only 0's flashing over my screen, so they are clearly there.

Why does isAllowed(bool, x, y) return false for (0,0), when there is clearly a 0 there?

Let me know if any more information is needed, thanks!

Comment: Use `cout << int(c[j]) << endl;`. You're printing the ASCII character, not the value. (`NULL` is simply `0`). And `map.ptr<unsigned char>(y)[x]` is can be rewritten simply as `map.at<uchar>(y,x)`, or if you use `Mat1b` as `map(y,x)`

Comment: @Miki This actually does print 0's, thanks. Follow-up question; why do i get the same result i had before if i do (unsigned char)c[j], but i get actual 0's if i do int(c[j])?

I had a bug where i collected and read int's from the Mat, but i wanted unsigned chars. When the mat was populated with 1's this would give me the numerical value of the contents of the 4 following cells.

Comment: If you print `uchar` data you get the ASCII value. To get the actual value you can cast to `int`. Since `uchar` is 1 byte and `int` is 4 bytes, if you assign an `int` value in a `uchar*` you're effectively writing on 4 `uchar`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved now, here are my mistakes for future reference:

1: When printing, @Miki pointed out that unsigned characters -> ASCII value gets printed, not numerical representation.

2: in isAllowedPosition(bool res, int x, int y), res has a primitive type. Aka this is pushed on the stack and not a reference to a memorylocation. When writing to it, i write to the local copy and not to the one passed in as an argumet.

Two possible fixes, either pass in a pointer to a memorylocation and write to that, or simply return the result.

Comment: Or just "return res;"

Answer (score 0):

Since your data type is `uchar` (aka `unsigned char`), you're printing the ASCII value. Use

```
cout << int(c[j]) << endl;
```

to print the actual value.

---

Also `map.ptr<unsigned char>(y)[x]` can be rewritten simply as `map.at<uchar>(y,x)`, or if you use `Mat1b` as `map(y,x)`

Comment: isAllowed(res, 0, 0) will still return false. I changed the method accordingly, casting to int before i compare.

unsigned char* c = map.ptr<unsigned char>(y);
int cellval = int(p[x]);
res = cellval == int(0);

Comment: You need to cast to int only to print out the value, not in your processing.